# Buildroot: Start a program before/instead of linux login and after X.org has started

Tags: linux, buildroot, uclinux

I would like to create a very small linux that boots up and loads a program into execution.
I am using Buildroot in this endeavor. 
It would be nice if I could install the X.org without any desktop management environment (like Gnome or the many others) and just run a GUI app that would display various functionalities.
I'd like to use it for accessing HDDs and USB sticks, to copy data from a partition to another.. simple tasks.. like this one.

I've started by following [this](http://agentoss.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/how-to-create-a-very-small-linux-system-using-buildroot/) tutorial and I will advance to this one [this](http://agentoss.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/building-a-tiny-x-org-linux-system-using-buildroot/) but first I want to see how I could start a program at boot time, before any login and shutdown the OS from that program or when that program exists (first No GUI program).
Until now I have manage to follow the first tutorial successfully.

But even more importantly it would be the question: how could I put together the Linux image and an app of my own so that if I create a bootable media (CD/USB stick) the linux would find it and run it?

The next question would be how would I start a  GUI app just after the X has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need X.org?

I'd try Qt first. It can run without X.org via frame buffer. See this link: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-linux.html

Another alternative were to use http://directfb.de/

To start an application you just need to create a startup script in /etc/init.d/

Comment: Wow..didn't knew that qt could do that.. that's great info. Thank you.